# Best replacement for var x = y || false

Tags: javascript

A codebase I'm working on contains many uses of the javascript 'default operator' such as:

```
var x = y || false;
```

I'm wondering what the best possible replacement to use in order to guarantee that the value is never undefined, null, etc. Should I replace them with "false" and check against the string? Should I replace them with their longhand counterpart (explicit checks for null and undefined)? Or does each use case need to be evaluated for something I'm not taking into account?

Comment: What's wrong with that way of doing it?

Comment: He seems to be afraid of legal values treated as false like 0 ''

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are falsy as well, so if you intend to use an if statement to check the value later you don't have to use `false` as a default. Using OR that way is generally done when setting a default value, a truthy one. Unless you explicitly need `false` it doesn't really make sense to use it as a default value, as it's *falsy* anyway if the OR continues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*undefined, null, **etc***"? What *is* your actual use case?

Comment: I mean I want to make sure that the default never evaluates to anything false.

Comment: if you "want to make sure that the default never evaluates to anything false", then what you have is fine. it's if you can't have 0 that you need to get picky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a non-falsy default when your input could be a valid falsy value, one way is to do two tests

```
if (!x && x !== 0) {
    x = 1; // 1 is the default value but 0 is a valid input
}
```

The advantage of doing it like this is you can exclude non-valid falsy values, e.g. `NaN`

---

This said, you may be better off casting or type checking

```
if (typeof x !== 'number') x = 1;
```

or

```
x = +x;
if (x !== x) x = 1; // NaN goes to default
```